# Getting element in a list with most characters

Tags: r, list

I have a list in R and I wanted to know how to get the element in it with the most characters.

I think it's something using `which()` and `nchar()`? This is what I tried:

```
cnt <- sapply(unformatted_list, nchar)
unformatted_list[which.max(cnt)]
```

Comment: It is probably not the most elegant solution,  but what you wrote should have worked. It worked for me. What is going wrong the code that you wrote yourself?

Comment: @G5W I would get this error: Error in base::which.max(x, ...) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about ties:

```
L <- c("Apple","Banana","Monkey","Drugs")
which.max(nchar(L))
[1] 2
```

If you care about ties:

```
which(nchar(L) %in% max(nchar(L)))
[1] 2 3
```